# Как добавлять в Set объекты одного класса сущностей?

Tags: java, jpa

Здравствуйте.
Есть класс сущностей

```
@Entity
public class Point implements Serializable {
         private String scoreString;

         public Point(String scoreString){
          this.scoreString = scoreString;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Point)) {
            return false;
        }
        Point other = (Point) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }   
}
```

а в главном классе есть

```
Set<Point> points = new LinkedHashSet<>();

Point point1 = new Point("0:0);
points.add(point1);
Point point2 = new Point("0:15);
points.add(point2);
Point point3 = new Point("0:30);
points.add(point3);
```

сколько ни добавляй объекты в эту коллекцию, там всегда один элемент.

Comment: Определите для класса `Point` методы `equals()` и `hashCode()`.

Comment: и проблема решится?

Answer (score 2):

`Set` позволяет хранить только уникальные объекты. Уникальность определяется путём сравнивания объектов через метод `Object#equals(Object object)`. У вас его стандартная имплементация, которая, видимо, выдаёт всегда `true`, т.к. сравнивает только (наверное) имя класса. Переопределите его так, чтобы однозначно определять являются ли два `Point` разными. Тогда работать всё будет правильно.

В `IDEA` есть даже плагин для этого - нажимайте `alt+insert` для винды и выирайте `hashCode+equals` - там укажите по каким полям объекта сравнивать и всё - код сам сгенерится.

Comment: Я добавил свою имплементацию метода equals выше. Может подскажете как в главном классе реализовать сравнение? Буду очень признателен.

Comment: @НиколайБеляков, какая-то странная у вас реализация. Код не должен компилироваться, т.к. в классе нет поля `id`. Даже если и есть, то вы его не где не указываете и, если так, то оно инициализируется значением по умолчанию и, засим, у всех объектов одинаковое. Вам, наверное, надо по полю `scoreString` сравнение делать, а не по `id`

Comment: в классе есть поле id, просто я не весь код класса представил

Answer (score 1):

А когда Вы создаете экземпляр Point, у Вас значение поля id инициализируется? 
Судя по коду, нет, а значит вот эта строчка (this.id == null && other.id != null) вернет false, 
эта строчка (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id)) так же вернет false, 
а сам метод equals вернет true. Получается, что два объекта с непроинициализированными id будут считаться одинаковыми, поэтому и не получается в Set положить больше одного экземпляра.

Comment: @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;                                                                                            Мне наверное следовало весь код класса представить. Я так понимаю id инициализируется автоматически. Спасибо однако за участие.

Comment: Id генерируется тогда, когда вы эту запись в БД сохраняете. Когда вы просто создаете объект через new, ничего нигде не генерируется. Воспользуйтесь автогенерацией методов equals() и hashcode() в Intellij Idea и все будет норм.

Answer (score 0):

Я пошел другим путем. Вместо сета использую Stack, проверяя неравенство полей scoreString последнего добавленного объекта и добавляемого.